# RewriteEngine doesn't affect URL rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to make simple URL rewriting (example: '/toto.html' will be displayed as '/toto' in the URL bar). I have the following code in my .htaccess file, located at the root of my server (/):

```
ErrorDocument 403 /
ErrorDocument 404 /
Options All +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -indexes
# Apache Rewrite Rules (-html extensions)
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

It does work: '/toto.html' is rewrited as '/toto'. However, the server keeps trying to redirect me to the page without the .html extension rather than simply rewriting it. I have read a lot of other documented issues about RewriteEngine being ignored and so on, and tried many things, without any success. The server is still trying to interpret the URL rather than just rewriting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one redirect rule and one rewrite rule:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /
ErrorDocument 404 /

Options All +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -indexes
# Apache Rewrite Rules (-html extensions)
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.html to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.html
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your solution and I'm still getting redirected toward the altered file name: 'toto.html' or 'toto'. I am looking for URL 'masking' (or rewriting), such that toto.html is displayed as 'toto' in the URL bar. Not redirection. I've read across the net that rewriteEngine is supposed to work fine but neither of the solutions proposed here currently work on the server... damn.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to perform. When I use your or my script it silently rewrite '/toto.html' to '/toto'. That's fine. However, and that's the point, it also tries to load '/toto' (resulting in a 404 error since the file does not exist). That's where I am stuck, and do not understand why...